# Consulta SQL followers

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas!

Tengo dos tablas (**users y relationship**) y quiero mostrar los followers (usuarios que yo sigo, pero ellos a mi no).

De momento solo tengo que me muestre los usuarios que yo sigo y ellos a mi también.

Consulta (Usuarios que se siguen):

```
select u.*
from relationship r
join relationship m
on m.idUser = r.idFollower and m.idFollower = r.idUser
join users u on u.id = r.idFollower
where r.idUser = 1 and r.status=1
```

**Tabla Users:**

```
- id
- name
- lastName
```

**Tabla Relationship**

```
- id
- idUser
- idFollower
```

**Ejemplo:** Si introduzco el usuario 1, me tendría que devolver el usuario 5 y 8, porque ellos a mi no me siguen.

[image: Relationship]

Comment: ¿Has intentado construir alguna consulta? Esto nos podría dar una idea de cómo orientarte y poder llegar a la solución que esperas ;)

Comment: Formula bien tu pregunta añade la consulta para ayudarte

Comment: quieres hacer en tu consulta SQL es los usuarios que no esten en seguidores?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la claúsula `NOT EXISTS` para no devolver los usuarios que siguen al usuario `1`:

```
select u.*
  from relationship r
  join users u
    on u.id = r.idFollower
 where r.idUser = 1
   and r.status = 1
   and not exists (select null
                     from relationship r2
                    where r2.idUser = r.idFollower
                      and r2.idFollower = r.IdUser
                      and r2.status = 1)
```

También se puede expresar la misma idea usando un `LEFT JOIN` si prefieres:

```
select u.*
  from relationship r
  join users u
    on u.id = r.idFollower
  left join relationship r2
    on r2.idUser = r.idFollower
   and r2.idFollower = r.IdUser
   and r2.status = 1
 where r.idUser = 1
   and r.status = 1
   and r2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
   select *
    from relationship r
    inner join Users m on m.id= r.idUser
    where r.idUser = 1 and r.status=1
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow Pero lo tiene lo que pasa es que no esta bien codificada